# Excel VBA function get data form another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Need to get data corresponding for specific client from a cell from another workbook for corresponding month, every month new sheet is added, for example, "01.2016", "02.2016", "03.2016"

Can I automate with VBA function?

```
  Function GetSUM()

  Dim strPath, strFile, strSheet, strRng, strRef, Result As String

  strPath = "\\Report_2016"
  strFile = "File_name_2016.xls"  
  strSheet = "06.2016"
  strRng = Range("C59").Address(3, 59, xlR1C1)

  strRef = "'" & strPath & "[" & strFile & "]" & strSheet & "'!" & strRng

  End Function
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `GetSUM` isn't returning anything and what's the point of the function if you don't pass anything in and are hardcoding the month within?

Comment: From what I can see, your syntax for referencing the other sheet is 100%

Answer (score 0):

you miss a "\" before the first "["

```
strRef = "'" & strPath & "\[" & strFile & "]" & strSheet & "'!" & strRng
```

Comment: @daba did you get through it?